# CKEditor 4 stylesSet - apply class for elements with specific parent

Tags: ckeditor

I have CKEditor 4.13.1 installed. I would like to create a custom style in `stylesSet` for adding a CSS class to the items of a *specific* UL.

```
CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add('new_style', [
  { name: `Items of a specific ul`, element: 'ul.specific > li', attributes: { class: 'some-class' } }
]);
```

There would be more of such rules, and since `li.some-class` has a meaning only in the context of `ul.specific`, I would like these items in the dropdown list of the CKEditor to be visible **only** when the cursor stays at **a child LI of `ul.specific`, and not for any LI**.

Is there a way to achieve this?